# How to compare python dictionaries based on specific key

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, xml, dictionary

I have data files of json and xml which return me account details of customer. They both have almost the same data in them and i have to verify it. It may have a single account or multiple. I have made the a dictionary of selected keys which i need to verify. I need help in:

1) Storing the multiple dictionaries somewhere so i can compare it.

2) And a way to compare them.

I am providing a sample data file which contain multiple accounts.

```
rest = {
  "ReqType": "CRI",
  "ReqUID": "1234567",
  "ResultCode": "00",
  "Message": "Success",
  "Records": 2,
  "OutData": [
    {
      "CNIC": "123456789",
      "PSTS": "P",
      "CUSTNO": "CHO7SM",
      "Accounts": {
        "NoAccounts": "1",
        "AccountList": [
          {
            "ACC#": "17327901207",
            "TITLE": "John",
            "TYPE": "C",
            "STYPE": "C4",
            "STPDESC": "ACCOUNT CURRENT",
            "REL": "N",
            "LBAL": "2500000",
            "ABAL": "2500000",
            "DECEASED": "N",
            "BLOCKED": "N",
            "INACTIVE": "N",
            "CLOSED": "N"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "CNIC": "123456789",
      "PSTS": "S",
      "CUSTNO": "CDG1R8",
      "Accounts": {
        "NoAccounts": "1",
        "AccountList": [
          {
            "ACC#": "17327900081",
            "TITLE": "John",
            "TYPE": "C",
            "STYPE": "C4",
            "STPDESC": "ACCOUNT CURRENT",
            "REL": "N",
            "LBAL": "3486039",
            "ABAL": "3486039",
            "DECEASED": "N",
            "BLOCKED": "N",
            "INACTIVE": "N",
            "CLOSED": "N"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

xml = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FCDB_RES_ENV>
    <FCDB_HEADER>
        <SOURCE>FCAT</SOURCE>
        <SERVICE>CustomerAccountsDetails</SERVICE>
        <OPERATION>CustomerAccountsDetails</OPERATION>
        <SOURCE_USERID>FCAT</SOURCE_USERID>
        <DESTINATION>FCDB</DESTINATION>
        <COUNTRYCODE>T001</COUNTRYCODE>
        <USERTYPE>ENS</USERTYPE>
        <LANGID>eng</LANGID>
        <CHANNELID>01</CHANNELID>
    </FCDB_HEADER>
    <FCDB_BODY>
        <CUSTACCOUNT>
            <CUSTNO>
                <CUSTNO>123456789</CUSTNO>
                <TYPECUST>C</TYPECUST>
                <NAMCUST>John</NAMCUST>
                <ADDRESS>
                    <ADDRESS1>ABC.</ADDRESS1>
                </ADDRESS>
            </CUSTNO>
            <ACCOUNT>
                <CUSTNO>123456789</CUSTNO>
                <ACCNO>17327901207</ACCNO>
                <ACCOUNTTITLE>John</ACCOUNTTITLE>
                <ACCOUNTTYPEDETAIL>C4</ACCOUNTTYPEDETAIL>
                <BALANCE>25000.00</BALANCE>
                <ACCTTYPE>C</ACCTTYPE>
                <ACCPRD>AAAA</ACCPRD>
                <ACCPRDDESC>ACCOUNT CURRENT</ACCPRDDESC>
                <ACCCCY>PKR</ACCCCY>
                <STATUS>A</STATUS>
                <RELATION>J</RELATION>
                <BAL_AVAIL>25000.00</BAL_AVAIL>
                <HASCHEQUE>true</HASCHEQUE>
                <HASOVERDRAFT>N</HASOVERDRAFT>
                <UNCLEARFUND>0.00</UNCLEARFUND>
            </ACCOUNT>
            <ACCOUNT>
                <CUSTNO>123456789</CUSTNO>
                <ACCNO>17327900081</ACCNO>
                <ACCOUNTTITLE>John</ACCOUNTTITLE>
                <ACCOUNTTYPEDETAIL>C4</ACCOUNTTYPEDETAIL>
                <BALANCE>34860.39</BALANCE>
                <ACCTTYPE>C</ACCTTYPE>
                <ACCPRD>AAAA</ACCPRD>
                <ACCPRDDESC>ACCOUNT CURRENT</ACCPRDDESC>
                <ACCCCY>PKR</ACCCCY>
                <STATUS>A</STATUS>
                <RELATION>J</RELATION>
                <BAL_AVAIL>34860.39</BAL_AVAIL>
                <HASCHEQUE>true</HASCHEQUE>
                <HASOVERDRAFT>N</HASOVERDRAFT>
                <UNCLEARFUND>0.00</UNCLEARFUND>
            </ACCOUNT>
            <ACCOUNT>
                <CUSTNO>123456789</CUSTNO>
                <ACCNO>17327900940</ACCNO>
                <ACCOUNTTITLE>Adam</ACCOUNTTITLE>
                <ACCOUNTTYPEDETAIL>C4</ACCOUNTTYPEDETAIL>
                <BALANCE>2004976.00</BALANCE>
                <ACCTTYPE>C</ACCTTYPE>
                <ACCPRD>AAAA</ACCPRD>
                <ACCPRDDESC>ACCOUNT CURRENT</ACCPRDDESC>
                <ACCCCY>PKR</ACCCCY>
                <STATUS>A</STATUS>
                <RELATION>J</RELATION>
                <BAL_AVAIL>2004976.00</BAL_AVAIL>
                <HASCHEQUE>true</HASCHEQUE>
                <HASOVERDRAFT>N</HASOVERDRAFT>
                <UNCLEARFUND>0.00</UNCLEARFUND>
            </ACCOUNT>
        </CUSTACCOUNT>
        <FCDB_ERROR_RESP>
            <ERROR>
                <ECODE>00</ECODE>
                <EDESC>Your transaction has been processed successfully.</EDESC>
            </ERROR>
        </FCDB_ERROR_RESP>
    </FCDB_BODY>
</FCDB_RES_ENV>
```

I have converted the soap response into a dictionary to get the items easily.

```
import json
import xmltodict
from collections import OrderedDict

rest_file = json.loads(rest.read())
doc = xmltodict.parse(xml.read())
input_dict = OrderedDict(doc)
xml_file = json.loads(json.dumps(input_dict))

a = xml['FCDB_RES_ENV']['FCDB_BODY']['CUSTACCOUNT']
for i in a.__getitem__('ACCOUNT'):
    xml_dict = {key: a[key] for key in a if key in ['ACCNO', 'ACCOUNTTITLE', 'ACCOUNTTYPEDETAIL', 'ACCPRDDESC']}
    print(soap_dict)
print("--------------------")

for item in rest.get('OutData'):
    b = (item.get('Accounts')['AccountList'])
    json_file_account = b.pop()

    rest_dict = {key: json_file_account[key] for key in json_file_account if key in
                 ['ACC#', 'TITLE', 'STYPE', 'STPDESC']}
    print(rest_dict)
```

The Output of above script is:

```
{'ACCNO': '17327901207', 'ACCOUNTTITLE': 'John', 'ACCOUNTTYPEDETAIL': 'C4', 'ACCPRDDESC': 'ACCOUNT CURRENT'}
{'ACCNO': '17327900081', 'ACCOUNTTITLE': 'John', 'ACCOUNTTYPEDETAIL': 'C4', 'ACCPRDDESC': 'ACCOUNT CURRENT'}
{'ACCNO': '17327900940', 'ACCOUNTTITLE': 'Adam', 'ACCOUNTTYPEDETAIL': 'C4', 'ACCPRDDESC': 'ACCOUNT CURRENT'}
--------------------
{'ACC#': '17327901207', 'TITLE': 'John', 'STYPE': 'C4', 'STPDESC': 'ACCOUNT CURRENT'}
{'ACC#': '17327900081', 'TITLE': 'John', 'STYPE': 'C4', 'STPDESC': 'ACCOUNT CURRENT'}
```

For Comparison, I need to iterate the first dictionary of xml into rest and see if AccNo matches then compare all values. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You need to append all dict into a list and then iterate over it and match the value of accounts.

Below is the modified code.

```
import json
import xmltodict
from collections import OrderedDict

rest_file = json.loads(rest.read())
doc = xmltodict.parse(xml.read())
input_dict = OrderedDict(doc)
xml_file = json.loads(json.dumps(input_dict))
soap_dict_list = []
a = xml['FCDB_RES_ENV']['FCDB_BODY']['CUSTACCOUNT']
for i in a.__getitem__('ACCOUNT'):
    xml_dict = {key: a[key] for key in a if key in ['ACCNO', 'ACCOUNTTITLE', 'ACCOUNTTYPEDETAIL', 'ACCPRDDESC']}
    print(soap_dict)
    soap_dict_list.append(soap_dict)
print(soap_dict_list)
print("--------------------")
rest_dict_list = []
for item in rest.get('OutData'):
    b = (item.get('Accounts')['AccountList'])
    json_file_account = b.pop()

    rest_dict = {key: json_file_account[key] for key in json_file_account if key in
                 ['ACC#', 'TITLE', 'STYPE', 'STPDESC']}
    print(rest_dict)
    rest_dict_list.append(rest_dict)
print(rest_dict_list)

# Now iterate over list
for info1 in rest_dict_list:
    for info2 in soap_dict_list:
        if info1['ACC#'] == info2['ACCNO']:
            print("Account number Match found")
            if info1['TITLE'] == info2['ACCOUNTTITLE']:
                print("ACCOUNTTITLE and TITLE matched")
            # and so on you can match rest of values
```

Answer (score 0):

Ali Khan,

1.) I would suggest grouping them by using keys alone since the keys seem to vary into a list groups.

2.) After grouping is completed try using pandas Dataframe package to compare.

Here is my code below to compare all those values.

```
import pandas as pd

df_struct = list()

df_struct.append({'ACCNO': '17327901207', 'ACCOUNTTITLE': 'John', 'ACCOUNTTYPEDETAIL': 'C4', 'ACCPRDDESC': 'ACCOUNT CURRENT'})
df_struct.append({'ACCNO': '17327900081', 'ACCOUNTTITLE': 'John', 'ACCOUNTTYPEDETAIL': 'C4', 'ACCPRDDESC': 'ACCOUNT CURRENT'})
df_struct.append({'ACCNO': '17327900940', 'ACCOUNTTITLE': 'Adam', 'ACCOUNTTYPEDETAIL': 'C4', 'ACCPRDDESC': 'ACCOUNT CURRENT'})

df = pd.DataFrame(df_struct)
print(df[df['ACCNO'].duplicated()])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. by the way i need to compare the soap_dict with rest_dict. I don't want to compare all of them with each other

Comment: Then you can create two dataframes and then compare them.